# Multiple artists contributing keyframes to a shared object?

Tags: animation, workflow, keyframes

I have a group of animators, all animating the same object. The object is a figure performing a dance. The gross body movement (body, limbs, neck/head) comes from a motion capture file. Each animator starts with the same avatar with these motions assigned to it.

The point of this project is to recreate extremely detailed hand and finger movements, which are part of this traditional dance. This is also true of facial and foot gestures. Because this is a learning exercise, I want each animator to focus on a range of frames, for a single one of these detailed areas. So, one animator would provide keyframes for the left hand from 0:00:00 to 0:30:00, another would do the same hand from 0:30:01 to 1:00:00 [m:s:f]. The same would be true for two other animators, on the other side of the body, and yet another pair for the head and face, and other animators would handle the feet.

How do these different teams extract only the keyframes they've contributed to a shared animation of the same figure? The goal here is to see what techniques each animator comes up with, and to have a single animation where the results can be seen and compared, while keeping each out the other's workspace.

In principle the merging process is happening across multiple workstations, but in practice it could be managed on a single machine.

For reference, this is the source video: https://youtu.be/BhJYdhtqyDc?t=35

Comment: Have you considered using NLA tracks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGKEL.png)? The horizontal dimension is time, and the vertical dimension would be the different parts of the body. This makes a 2D grid of which each person would work on one cell. At the end you'd link all the actions into one .blend and arrange them into the grid.

Comment: @scurest: I see the concept but how would it be possible for two different people to work on two different tracks in this way in the same file at the same time? The key challenge (for me) is how to isolate the work done by one person, copy it, and transfer only that to another project. I get how this works if the file is handed from person to person, but who sequentially make changes. I guess at the minimum it would take the form of an xml file that could be output, and then merged somehow....

Comment: One blend per person, all with the same armature/mesh, each one working on a different action. At the end you link/append all the actions into one blend and setup the full NLA tracks.

Comment: Would it work, for instance, to have an animator work on one hand, and then, after saving the file, delete all the bones and other components, except for. the area (let's say the right arm), then import that to a master file, where it would then be moved into the object hierarchy? This wouldn't allow different sequences in time like 0:00:00 ==> 0:30:00, as well as 0:30:01 ==> 1:00:00, because those would be the same bones, so the latest would overwrite the earlier. But at least, would it allow me to isolate animation on extremities in this way?

Comment: I was commenting as you were, @scurest. I think I see where you're going. Would this also work for time subsequences though, as asked about in my previous comment? In other words, I guess the question is, can I append a range of armature keyframes delimited in time? ADD: as I think about it, the mesh doesn't really come into this, it's purely about the bones for the relevant area.

Comment: You can put multiple actions one after another in the track. See the image in my first comment.